# Errors with a movieClip class

Tags: class, actionscript

I have defined a class as

```
package telmate.com.audioB.volume {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Volume_Bar extends MovieClip {
    public static const BAR_WIDTH = 20;

    public function Volume_Bar(op: Number, vol: Number) {
        alpha = Util.clamp(op);
        volume = vol;
    }
    
    private _volume:Number;// do we even need to store this?
    
    public function set volume(v: Number){
        _volume = v;
        var f:uint = Util.clamp(v * totalFrames, 0, totalFrames - 1) + 1;
        gotoAndStop(f);
    }

}

}
```

and I am getting two errors: I am calling the constant BAR_WIDTH and instantiating it with parameters - new Volume_Bar(op, vol) -- and getting

> /Users/dave/Documents/Audio/telmate/com/audioB/Audio_Bars.as, Line 152
>
> **1136:** Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 0.

and

> /Users/dave/Documents/Audio/telmate/com/audioB/Audio_Bars.as, Line 156
>
> **1119:** Access of possibly undefined property BAR_WIDTH through a
> reference with static type Class.

Why would this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know how specific I can be here, but...

That first error message indicates that when you're calling a function, you're passing arguments, but the function is not set up to handle arguments. Have you adjusted either the function itself, or the line of code that is calling it? (If you're calling through an event listener, be sure to include an argument in the function to hold the referring event. See documentation.)

What specifically is on Audio_bars.as, Line 152? That's where the error is occurring.

The second error seems to indicate that you haven't declared a function/variable by the name of "BAR_WIDTH". In reading your code, there doesn't appear to be an error in the declaration. Thus, you may be having [a weird issue I've had before.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9507999/472647)

Hope that helps!