# Public Function Allegedly Doesn't Exist?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

Okay, I am at the end of my rope.

I have a Flash Professional CS5.5, Adobe AIR, Actionscript 3 project. So far, I've never had this problem before...

I have a custom class called Prefs, that I wrote myself. This class has a number of functions. The ones I wrote a couple weeks ago, I can call in my code with no problem. But the ones in the SAME CLASS that I wrote today are throwing an error.

This one works:

```
public function UserFetch(ID:String):*
{
```

This one doesn't:

```
public function Set(setting:String, val:*):void
{
```

I call both the same way. In the document class "base":

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import trailcrest.prefs.prefs;

    public class base extends MovieClip {

        public static var Prefs:prefs = new prefs();
    }

}
```

In my timeline code.

```
base.Prefs.UserFetch("musictoggle");
base.Prefs.Set("musictoggle", true);
```

The first fires fine. The second gives this error:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 4 1061: Call to a possibly
>   undefined method Set through a reference with static type
>   prefs.

What is going on? I can find absolutely no legitimate reason why this should be happening. Like I said, it has never happened before, and it not happening on any other class or function.

Comment: In the code you show here, you haven't declared any SetMusicVolume function (you have declared one named Set).

Comment: Pasted the wrong one. I fixed it. --NOTE: PROBLEM IS SAME. NOT RESOLVED--

Comment: Now you have to fix the error you listed. Your error says undefined method 'SetMusicVolume', which you now say is not the problem method.

Comment: Edited that, thank you. I've been staring at code for the past three days. I'm a bit dippy with the copy and paste, lol.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the method? Set may be a reserved word/name.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Four different functions ("Set" "SetMusicVolume", "SetSFXVolume", and "Testing") are all throwing the same stupid error.

Comment: Hmm. My best guess is you have an extra `}` somewhere, before the declaration of those functions. Otherwise it's impossible to say what's wrong with the limited source you provided.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8366/discussion-between-jasonmc92-and-sam-dehaan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of discussion in the chat, we found that flash was not picking up on the changes made in the `prefs.as`-file. Changing the name of the class fixed the issue (It may have been a weird compiler cache problem).

Comment: One of the weirdest things I've ever seen. But thanks for helping me find the problem.

Comment: "SET" is a keyword and you should't use it. As for the problem you need to set the "Set" function to static. Chances are he added it when he changed the name of the class and didn't realize it. If you assign the instance of the class to static you will only be able to access the static methods in that class.

Comment: `Set` is not a keyword (`set` is), and it works fine. Set does not need to be set to static - there was a static instance of the prefs class in the base class that he accessed. The problem was resolved, and it had nothing to do with staticness.