# AS3 call to possibly undefined method

Tags: actionscript-3

I get a very similar problem when I uncomment the mcMain. method calls. When I try to call an instance on the stage it says "1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class."

I have done similar stuff before on another computer and I am not sure why this is doing this. I am Using Adobe Flash CS5.5 and AS3.0.

```
//These variables will note which keys are down
//We don't need the up or down key just yet
//but we will later
var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var upKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var downKeyDown:Boolean = false;
//the main character's speed
var mainSpeed:Number = 7;

//adding a listener to mcMain which will make it move
//based on the key strokes that are down
mcMain.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
function moveChar(event:Event):void
{
    //if certain keys are down then move the character
    if (leftKeyDown)
    {
        trace("left");
        //mcMain.x -= mainSpeed;
    }
    if (rightKeyDown)
    {
        trace("right");
        //mcMain.x += mainSpeed;
    }
    //if(upKeyDown || mainJumping){
    ////mainJump();
    //}
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtR7F.png

Comment: Just a heads up, as I've had this happen before. There is a rare bug that can cause this type of thing. If there is NO problems with your code at all, check how I fixed mine: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9507999/472647

Answer (score 1):

I believe from your screenshot that you named the object mcMain as the class name but not as the instance of the object's name.  Click the properties panel and give the instance a name, that's the name you'll use to refer to it in AS3, the other name you made is what you would use if you wanted to make new instances of the object in AS3 (it's effectively the class name).

Answer (score 0):

Check how `mcMain` is defined. Should be something like `var mcMain:MovieClip;`.

Comment: well I have the instance on the stage already and the instance name is set in properties to mcMain, should I create the instance within the actionscript code?

Comment: @Travis you have a new symbol that extends MovieClip and is named mcMain however you don't show an instance name in your screen shot.  When an instance is dragged from the library onto the stage that itself is an instance of the Class mcMain, if you go to the properties panel with that instance selected you can set an instance id.